# UIButton форма кнопки

Tags: swift, spritekit, uibutton

Как прописать, чтобы кнопка нажималась ровно по форме картинки? У меня сейчас если нажимаешь в окрестностях кнопку, она тоже реагирует

```html
Knopka = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (self.view?.frame.size.width)! / 2 - 95, y: (self.view?.frame.size.height)! / 2 - 170), size: CGSize(width: 185, height: 195)))
        Knopka.setImage(UIImage(named: "Knopka1"), forState: .Normal)
        Knopka.addTarget(self, action: Selector("perexod"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view?.addSubview(Knopka)
```

[image: Форма кнопки]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте класс, вставьте данный код:

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func alphaFromPoint(point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        var pixel: [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(&pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);
        self.layer.renderInContext(context!)
        let floatAlpha = CGFloat(pixel[3])
        return floatAlpha
    }
}

class AlphaTouchableButton: UIButton {
    override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return self.alphaFromPoint(point) > 0
    }
}
```

При добавлении кнопки программно используйте `AlphaTouchableButton` вместо `UIButton`.

При добавлении через интерфейс билдер пропишите своей кнопке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь кнопка будет нажиматься только в местах где есть изображение и нет прозрачности.

Comment: А как быть если в интерфейс билдере нет кнопки, у меня SpriteKit я просто кодом ее создаю

Comment: @Leci замените в коде UIButton на AlphaTouchableButton

Comment: Все отлично, спасибо за помощь)