# Разделение изображения на области

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, swift3

Возможно ли разделить изображение на области и по нажатию на каждую совершать какое-либо действие? В моем примере по нажатию на отдельные детали танка показывать соответствующие деталям названия. Может есть какие-то библиотеки с подобным решением? Спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: такой вопрос точно раньше был. там человеку надо было обрабатывать нажатие не на всю кнопку, а только на ее часть

Comment: Как Вы это хотите делать? Задать полигон?

Comment: Можете глянуть этот вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/531925/uibutton-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8/531951#531951 . Вот только там все изображение это одна область. Как Вы думаете разделять эти области у Вашего изображения?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете попробовать реализовать это с помощью  [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit).

Картинки идут в формате SVG, с помощью библиотеки SVGKit вы можете получить CALayerы для отображения SVG, дальше уже обрабатывать нажатие и делать все что нужно(выделять, отобразить кастовое окно)

Например из такого SVG изображения: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно сделать такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]